# Inserting Block with Custom Input Filter Module via Shortcode Causing http 500 error

Tags: 7, blocks, input-formats

I have a custom input filter module, and I am trying to figure out why it crashes when I attempt to insert a block into a post via a shortcode. The method works perfectly when I am inserting a string, but when I try to insert a block, it causes a http 500 error.

Any ideas? I am using Drupal 7.15. Also, I have tried the [insert_block](http://drupal.org/project/insert_block) module, and it generates a similar error...

**Here is the input filter process that works (with a string)**

```
function _related_links_filter_related_block_process($text, $filter, $format) {
   $shortcode_regexp  = "/\[block\]/";
   $output = "Text string inserted in via shortcode";

   return preg_replace($shortcode_regexp, $output,$text);
}
```

**Here is the input filter process that causes the error (with a block)**

```
function _related_links_filter_related_block_process($text, $filter, $format) {
   $shortcode_regexp  = "/\[block\]/";
   $block = block_load('block', 3);
   $output = drupal_render(_block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block))));

   return preg_replace($shortcode_regexp, $output,$text);
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A 500 error can be caused by lots of things. Your best bet is probably to use the [Watchdog](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/watchdog) and/or [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html) logs to narrow down the specific cause(s).

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way to do it without the 500 error, I tried loading a block in a different way and it worked. Don't know why module_invoke() works over block_load(), if someone can explain.

```
function _related_links_filter_related_block_process($text, $filter, $format) {
   $shortcode_regexp  = "/\[block\]/";
   $block = module_invoke('block', 'block_view', 3);
   $output = render($block['content']);

   return preg_replace($shortcode_regexp, $output,$text);
}
```